# What is the purpose of the passenger seat in vehicles in Far Cry 6?

Tags: far-cry-6

In *Far Cry 5*, the player character could have a human companion. If you entered a vehicle using the passenger seat the human companion would automatically enter the driver's seat and would drive that vehicle to any location that you marked on your map.

The player character could then man any weapons positions on the vehicle, or fire a weapon from the passenger seat.

*Far Cry 6* has the same passenger seat mechanic, but since it doesn't have human companions you can't do anything much except sit in the seat.

Is this it, or are there other game mechanics that I've missed?

Comment: Probably because there's co-op mode? I remember far cry had co-op mode since 4 or something.